# Neo4j -can't start the db in dev JVMs error

Tags: neo4j

I am using Mac and OS is Yosemite.
I executed first the command:

rails new my-new-app -m

This was OK and after that I executed:

rake neo4j:install[community-2.2.0,development]

This was also ok.

I cannot start the db and I am getting the error:

rake neo4j:start

Starting Neo4j development...
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded jdk-7u75-macosx-x64.dmg package and installed the JVM.